# Function overloaded with error code C2660

Tags: c, pointers

I am having an issue with this pointer.
I am pretty sure that there is someone out there with the answer to my problem...

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char str_a[20];
    char *pointer;
    char *pointer2;

    strcpy_s(str_a, "Dear World!\n");
    pointer = str_a;
    printf(pointer);

    pointer2 = pointer + 2;
    printf(pointer2);
    strcpy_s(pointer2, "idn't even notice!\n");
    printf(pointer);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

I get the

> error code C2660

What can I do about it?

Comment: when posting a question like this , please include the full message, that way we can see what line it is complaining about

Comment: strcpy_s takes more arguments see https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy, and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23307268/how-does-strcpy-s-work

Comment: I'm sorry but that was not much help. Thanks tho.

Comment: well it tells you the answer, so its should be really helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to change your strcpy_s calls to include destination size

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char str_a[20];
    char *pointer;
    char *pointer2;

    strcpy_s(str_a,sizeof(str_a), "Dear World!\n");
    pointer = str_a;
    printf(pointer);

    pointer2 = pointer + 2;
    printf(pointer2);
    strcpy_s(pointer2, sizeof(str_a) -2,("idn't even notice!\n");
    printf(pointer);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

PS - you could have worked this out from my comment that pointed you at the documentation for strcpy_s

Comment: OK I'll give it another go. I just don't want to give up because i don't get it. Thank you still.

Comment: Are these kind of mistakes common for noobs? Do you have any tips for avoiding future errors of any type?

Comment: sadly very common. read the error message , consult the documentation. You have to work at this kind of thing, dont go 'well that didnt work, probably too hard for me to understand - I give  up'

Comment: and when you ask a question and get a comment dont say 'I'm sorry but that was not much help' when in fact if gives you the exact answer

Comment: Hahaha thanks, I hear what you're saying. Dick move on my part.